# Do I need to learn AC circuits for working with micro-controller projects?

Tags: digital-logic, ac, dc

I am a Computer engineering student. I am very interested in micro-controllers, FPGA, and digital design projects, and actually, I am good at these topics. In addition to that, I have a good knowledge of DC circuit analysis.

My problem is in AC circuits. I am just not that good at it. My question is: would I really need AC circuit theory as a computer engineer interested in DC electronics applications only (digital circuits, micro-controllers, FPGA, etc.)

I think once you feed a circuit with DC current through a power supply, from here on it is just DC stuff.

If the answer is “yes I need AC”, then how much of it (the required topics), do I need?

Comment: You will need AC theory as soon as you start dealing with voltages that change over time.

Comment: Seriously, have you never seen someone spell Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Breadboarding a Raspberry Pi](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96538/breadboarding-a-raspberry-pi)

Comment: You never know what you are going to end up doing in your career. In order to work with high speed signals, it is very helpful to understand basic system response (under-damp, over-damp, critically damped), transmission lines and impedance matching, and Fourier concepts. However, do not be discouraged if you are better at some subjects than others. Also, sometimes a subject which is initially difficult may become more intuitive after some time passes and you re-read the same material later.

Comment: To be a real ee, even if you only do fpga, you need all of ac you can get

Comment: i am not EE, i am CE

Comment: Maybe it would help us if you explain why you are asking. Are you trying to decide what classes to take, or are you afraid that you are not cut out for this field because you did poorly in an AC analysis course? If you are discouraged, my main advice is don't worry. Not everybody does well in every class. You can't make career decisions on a poor grade in one class. Also, some people are strictly digital designers, and that is OK. They let others worry about signal integrity, timing, etc.

Comment: thank you for your answer  mkeith
actually i have already taken (and passed ) AC circuit theory class. but really hated it . and that was 4 years ago and now forgot all of it. now i don't really feel like spending the next 6 months re-studying:
Magnetic Circuits,
Resonance,
Decibels, Filters, and Bode Plots,
Transformers,
Polyphase Systems,
Pulse Waveforms and the R-C Response,
Nonsinusoidal Circuits,

it is just not my type of math and i really hate it.
by the way those were the chapter titles from the second half of my circuit theory textbook

Comment: "i have already taken (and passed ) AC circuit theory class. but really hated it... it is just not my type of math" - the real purpose of those classes is not to learn all the math, but to know what math to use _when you need it_. So don't worry about it, you can always 're-study' when the need arises. 99% of board-level digital circuit design can be done without any advanced math.

Comment: At speeds up to 1MHz or maybe even 10MHz you won't need to know AC theory in practice for microcontroller projects; just treat it as changing DC. By the time you get to more than that, stuff like transmission line effects start to become apparent. At 10MHz you still have 30 metres of wavelength, and a 10cm trace won't be really noticeable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about career education advice, rather than posting a specific technical question.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Agreed. VTC.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you need AC.

High-speed microprocessors like those used in boards such as RaspberryPi are running at high speeds — not DC at all — and you need to have a solid grounding in things like transmission line theory if you're going to connect one to an external memory chip successfully on a scratch-built board. Not to mention high-speed I/O interfaces such as Ethernet, WiFi, LVDS, etc.

Power conversion circuits that are typically used in such boards also require AC theory in order to calculate things like stability and transient response.

If you really don't want to get involved with that and you prefer to focus on the digital side of things, I would recommend that you work with existing boards and evaluation modules that are available from various vendors. There are hundreds of them out there, and they take care of all of that nasty "AC stuff" for you.

---

You mention "Arduino" in passing; most things that fall into that category use much slower microcontrollers (tens or hundreds of MHz, rather than GHz+). Anyone and his brother can design one of those boards — and for the most part, they already have! The only reason to do a custom board would be to make one for a complete specific application.

Comment: Would probably be worth pointing out that there's a big difference between designing an Arduino and designing a Raspberry Pi board..

Comment: My brother can't :-)

Comment: ok forget what i said about the  Raspberry Pi, my goal is just micro-controller projects ( i have update the question title)

Comment: Don't learn ac, make the competition easier for us

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, there are two things people could mean when they talk about AC systems: Power electronics or frequency domain analysis.

You can live a pretty happy life with just a basic understanding of power electronics and not doing much with transformers or wall voltages. There are a lot of opportunities for folks who excel at power system designs, but fortunately they've also made app notes and reference designs we can just copy.

Frequency domain stuff, like understanding the functions of a filter or how a waveform will be changed by a capacitor, is a fundamental part of electrical/computer engineering, and it helps you understand why you don't want your 200 MHz DDR RAM to be too far from your chip, or why one FPGA layout works and another doesn't.

It really depends what kind of work you want to do. In my experience, there are CS folks who just want to work inside the chip, and they tend to be stronger on the OS and OOP side. The EE/CE folks can focus inside the chip, but are expected to do some schematic and board design work as well, and that tends to get into frequency domain work. I've worked with folks who shut down when I started talking about impedance and frequency response, and it meant I could not work with them on very technical stuff.

Comment: thank you for your answer. so for the type of work i have described in the question explanation above, could you please tell me the chapter numbers that i must study from my circuit theory textbook:
http://www.powells.com/book/introductory-circuit-analysis-10th-edition-9780130974174  
i have a good understanding of the topics in chapters: 1 to 9

Comment: @Pulsar It looks like the book does deal with frequency domain stuff, but it seems to be doing that without talking about the frequency domain or Fourier transform directly. A key engineering skill is figuring out and understanding the impedance of a circuit, for example knowing when an RC filter will attenuate by 50%.

I would say, go to the library, grab Art of Electronics by Horowitz and Hill. Look through the first few chapters, if that looks like stuff you can follow, you're ok. If you get filled with hate, maybe go to the CS side :)

Answer (score 0):

If all of your work is purely logical without any need to analyze nor design actual electric circuitry, you can perform well without doing AC circuit calculations nor understanding them more deeply than an ordinary user.

Do not think that you can allways select what you are expected to do. The narrower is your zone of comfort, the more likely you will get pulled out of there by others who don't waste one second by thinking of your pleasure, they only want to get the urgent job done, done straight now and without excuses.

Obviously some part of you have already realized it and made the rest of you to suspect, can you really exclude the understanding of AC.

You haven't to be a brilliant AC (including radio and pulse circuits) designer, but you should understand them and do it well. Otherwise you cannot make any relevant decisions on the construction of the actual circuitry.

Comment: Sort of.  You can do crude student/hobbyist projects, or be a software engineer who occasionally pokes at hardware.  But to design marketable circuitry, you need to understand at least the *implications* of the frequency domain concerns - you might not calculate it the way someone building radio gear would, but you need to build an ability to imagine the *shape* of the math.  Traditionally, you get that by doing the fully analysis a few times in school.

Answer (score 0):

As you develop boards for sell, the EMC/EMI/susceptibility goals will require you to understand AC concepts.